# replace pandas column value with increments of numbers

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Account':['Paul','Jenn']}


df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

[image]

The desired output would be 1 for paul and 2 for Jenn, the basis of the solution would form a for loop for a much bigger dataset to replace account number names with numeric values

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:  First create a dictionary mapping of the unique names in Accounts to the number ordered by how they appear.  Then use `.replace()` to replace the values in the series with this number.  This will ensure that Paul is always replaced by 1 if it appears more than once and Jenn is replaced by 2 if it appears more than once, etc.

```
import pandas
import json


data = {'Account':['Paul','Jenn']}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=data)

name_mapping = json.loads(pandas.Series(
    index=df.Account.unique(),
    data=range(1, len(df.Account.unique()) + 1)
).to_json())

df.Account = df.Account.replace(name_mapping)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Account
0        1
1        2
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to do, please futher elaborate if i misunderstood the question :)
If you want to replace the 'name' column with index incremented by a value:

```
df['name'] = df.index + value
```

Increase the values of a column (or do any other arithmetical operation over a column) :

```
df['column name'] += value
# add do that over a column and add it to another column
df['result'] += df['other column'] + value
```

Count the number of occurences for each value in column name

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["Paul", "Jenn", "Paul"]})
# count the number of occurences for each name
df["count"] = df.groupby("name")['name'].transform('count')
# in case you don't want duplicate rows
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```